# any way to invoke fragment identifiers '#' in python

Tags: python, url, mechanize, fragment-identifier

Is there any way to invoke fragment identifiers from python?  I'm currently using python mechanize.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you're trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "invoke fragment identifier"?

Comment: @Rafe Kettler and @sth: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798422/why-urllib2-urlopen-can-not-open-pages-like-http-localhost-new-postcomment-29. 'Fragment' in this context appears to be the '#blah-blah-blah' hanging off the end of a URL. The idea is to navigate within a page. OP wants to get the stuff at that point, I gather.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798422/why-urllib2-urlopen-can-not-open-pages-like-http-localhost-new-postcomment-29) holds your answer:

> In the HTTP protocol, the fragment
>   (from # onwards) is not sent to the
>   server across the network: it's
>   locally retained by the browser and
>   used, once the server's response is
>   fully received, to somehow "visually
>   locate" the exact spot in the page to
>   be shown as "current" (for example, if
>   the returned page is in HTML, this
>   will be done by parsing the HTML and
>   looking for the first suitable 
>   flag).

And Alex Martelli's recommendation for action also holds:

> So, the procedure is: remove the
>   fragment e.g. via urlparse.urlparse;
>   use the rest to fetch the resource;
>   parse it appropriately based on the
>   server response's content-type header;
>   then take whatever visual action your
>   program does regarding the "current
>   spot" on the resource, based on
>   locating within the parsed resource
>   the fragment you retained in the first
>   step.